# How to properly structure my ansible playbook when sharing tasks between roles

Tags: ansible, dry

I am trying to follow best pratices in designing my ansible playbook. So the playbook file itself looks like this:

```
- hosts: ...
roles:
 - dbservers
 - webservers
 - ...
```

Now there is a task `check_proxy_and_firewalls` that I want to execute in the `dbserers` as well as in `webservers` roles.

How would I properly structure that? All the "best_practice" guides I find do not seem to consider this case.

I could simple add a file `common_tasks/check_proxy_and_firewalls.yml` and include it in the roles where I need this. Is that how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to reuse tasks from other playbooks is as you stated, by using an include.

> Suppose you want to reuse lists of tasks between plays or playbooks. You can use include files to do this. Use of included task lists is a great way to define a role that system is going to fulfill.

From: [Ansible Playbook Roles](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html)

To include a file simply add this to your playbook:

```
  - include: path/to/task.yml
```

Structuring your roles largely depends on what you're using Ansible for. For example, I manage Windows and Linux servers so my roles are structured like this:

```
roles
  windows
    <some_function>
       tasks
       vars
  linux
    <some_function>
       tasks
       vars
```

Yours will be different depending on what your goals with ansible are.

Comment: Ok, where do you put a Task that belongs to multiple roles?

Comment: There isn't a be-all location for shared tasks, just like there isn't one for roles themselves. Personally, I'd place them in a location that required as few keystrokes as possible to include in a playbook. So somewhere like shared/tasks/main.yml

Comment: Also if this is just a one-off or similar, I might not even bother separating it from the role itself and I'd just include the file from whichever role I originally created it under.